# IONIC : http request work in browser and dev app but not in apk

Tags: android, angular, http, ionic-framework

I have a probleme with `Http` `angular in ionic`. I made some post requests to my server and everything work in the browser and the mobile with the `devapp (ionic serve --devapp)`, but when i build my `apk`, then sign it, i install the `apk` in my android phone, the the post dont work !

I tried also with the `native http`, but it dont work also !
Any help please

Comment: Are you using Angular's proxy?

Comment: No, is it required for rhis case ?

Comment: No, but I recently had an issue with the exact behavior you describe and that was the cause

Comment: and how did you fixe it ?

Comment: The issue was that the proxy did not work on the APK version of the app, we added an interceptor to do the proxy's job and that fixed the issue

Comment: Instead of `ionic serve` try the run app with `ionic cordova run browser -l`  and show what get you in the console of the browser.

Comment: Or try Android Remote Debugging with Chrome: https://ionic.zone/debug/remote-debug-your-app#android

Comment: i found a solution, it about ssl ! all that i did is change the AndroidManifest by adding cleartexttrafficpermitted = true. see documentation bellow :https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Comment: Thanks to your help ;)